# How are CSS properties implemented by different browsers?

Tags: css

This is a kind-of academic question. I was just wondering how different browsers implement CSS properties such as colours and gradients?

I have found some information online, but I am failing to *really* understand it.

Please explain in simple terms.

Comment: How? With varying degrees of malice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers, for the most part, follow various specifications.

Colours and gradients are defined in various CSS specifications which are maintained by the [World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/) (W3C). The CSS2 specification, for instance, can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/.

Sometimes these specifications are a bit vague, which leads to differences between how different browsers implement similar features.

To further answer your question. Section 14 of the specification I've linked to above deals with [Colors and Backgrounds](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html). This is now outdated, however, and has been replaced by two Level 3 modules: [Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) and [Color Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/). Background gradients are actually documented in [Image Values and Replaced Content Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients). An example from the latter:

> A gradient is an image that smoothly fades from one color to another. These are commonly used for subtle shading in background images, buttons, and many other things. The gradient notations described in this section allow an author to specify such an image in a terse syntax, so that the UA can generate the image automatically when rendering the page. The syntax of a `<gradient>` is:
>
> ```
> <gradient> = [ 
>     <linear-gradient> | <radial-gradient> | 
>     <repeating-linear-gradient> | <repeating-radial-gradient> ]
> ```

In the various specifications available, the term *User Agent* (shortened to *UA*, as seen in the above quote) is used to refer to the browser and how the browser should implement the features being discussed.

Comment: nice answer. there is a big difference between different browsers work